# Workaround for Entity Framework simple names restriction?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a part of a model like this:

```
public class RepeatDetails
{
    public enum Types { Daily = 0, Weekly = 1, Monthly = 2, Yearly = 3 }

    public Types Type { get; set; }
    public DailyDetails Daily { get; set; }

    public class DailyDetails
    {
        public enum Types { EveryDay = 0, EveryWorkingDay = 1 }
        public Types Type { get; set; }

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

When I try to *add-migration*, I get an error:

> The type 'MyProject.RepeatDetails+DailyDetails+Types' and the type
>   'MyProject.RepeatDetails+Types' both have the same simple name of
>   'Types' and so cannot be used in the same model. All types in a given
>   model must have unique simple names. Use 'NotMappedAttribute' or call
>   Ignore in the Code First fluent API to explicitly exclude a property
>   or type from the model.

I know that's EF restriction, you can't use same simple types. What I can do now is to rename these options with RepeatDetailsTypes, DailyDetailsTypes, etc. But I don't want to modify my model only because of restrictions of third-party library/libraries (moreover, this restriction could be removed in the next versions of EF). I want to keep **my** code clean and easier for other developers. If I run this way, I can end up with a huge mess inside of my code.

So I wonder, is there any workaround to keep the model clean and use it with EF? Maybe some kind of attributes or whatever? Any examples would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you use a modelbuilder, doesnt that solve it?

Comment: @RogerAlsing, how it could be solved with model builder? Any examples if I can ask, please? Thx.

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes any difference, but it lets you set the names for the columns/tables used with your code first model .. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/165720/Using-the-Code-First-Model-Configuration-Classes

Comment: Yep, but it changes nothing. I tried to modify the column name, but it just doesn't work.

Comment: How would attributes keep your model clean? Anyway, sooner or later you will modify your model to accommodate EF, for example, by using `virtual` modifiers or parameterless constructors. Every ORM I've worked with so far has had its footprint in the class model. EF is relatively modest, but inevitable. I see no way to skirt around this `enum` issue.

Comment: @GertArnold, at least when I try to access my types from other places, I won't see attributes. So that they can make my code cleaner.

Comment: It looks like the EF team is planning to (eventually) remove this restriction, at least for code-first models.  See: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/03/11/ef6-nested-types-and-more-for-code-first/